# Angular firestore drag & drop tasks list backend update

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, drag-and-drop

Using angular material CDK for drag and drop and firebase as a backend.

Everything works well but after the Firestore backend update, it is creating a new task instead of an update. Why?

```
taskDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        this.board.tasks,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
    this.boardService.updateTasks(this.board.id, this.board.tasks);
  }
```

How can I update task when it changes the list?

```
updateTasks(boardId: string, tasks: Task[]) {
    return this.db
      .collection('boards')
      .doc(boardId)
      .update({ tasks });
  }
```

Used the cdkDropListGroup directive to set up the connection automatically.

```
<ng-container cdkDropListGroup>
  <app-board cdkDrag *ngFor="let board of boards" [board]="board">
    <mat-icon cdkDragHandle class="handle">drag_indicator</mat-icon>
  </app-board>
</ng-container>
```

How can I solve this?